# .htaccess rules error in my website

Tags: .htaccess

I am using following `.htaccess` rule in my localhost :

**.htaccess file :**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

AddHandler cgi-script .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI
```

so that, url is showing something like that :

**www.mysite.com/about**

Now, when I upload all files with `.htaccess` file to my web address it's showing following error message :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /team-building.php on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

How can I solve this error and You see that I am using not-found error document rules in `.htaccess` file. But it's not showing me the error message page if the url is wrong.

**Note :** For testing purpose I am using sub-domain:

**sub domain : http://www.demo.mysite.com**
and all current files is in `public_html/demo/` folder.

Comment: @anubhava the file is in demo folder which now I am working.

Comment: @arkascha what should it be ?

Comment: Sorry, I removed my comment, it was wrong. I didn't pay enough attention when reading your code. Sorry.

Comment: @anubhava I tested it but showing 403 error message. First I have to solve the 403 error message then using your given test url I can check it.

Comment: Folder permissions of the file system folders?

Comment: And please also post your virtual host definition. Something might be wrong with the file system setup there.

Comment: @arkascha, don't get you ?

Comment: @anubhava I am checking it

Comment: @anubhava still error

Comment: ok replace `Options` line by `Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: If I remove the .htaccess file from the service then it's showing me the home page correct but not inner page.

Comment: @anubhava now it's showing me : Internal Server Error

Comment: You should check your Apache error.log file

Comment: Apache error log : [Sun Apr 17 03:38:33.670991 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 812900:tid 140580812154624] [client 103.242.219.250:26377] AH02809: Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /home/sitename/public_html/demo/403.shtml

Comment: HEY : Now it's working : I am now using only following rules : RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: But how can I show the page not found page ?

Comment: Add `ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.shtml` at top

Comment: Not Working : Showing : Not Found

The requested URL /sdfdf was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: http://demo.mysite.com/not-found and http://demo.mysite.com/not-found.php If I put these 2 url then it's showing my my error page. But it's should be show when I put wrong url.

Comment: Working Now. Change this to : ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubhava :)